# Json Object coming with Escape Strings

Tags: android, json, asmx

I am running on an issue for hours, I created a webservice which is returning the following Json String (by Using JavaScriptSerializer lib in .net:

```
{"d":"[{\"Id\":4,\"Description\":\"\\u003cp\\u003eExcelente Apartamento com 02 dormit\\u0026oacute;rios, primeiro andar, um lance de escada, de frente, todo reformado, sala, cozinha\/\\u0026aacute;rea de servi\\u0026ccedil;o. Condom\\u0026iacute;nio tradicional, super organizado, com portaria 24h, playground, quadra poliesportiva, Sal\\u0026atilde;o de festa, quiosques\\u003c\/p\\u003e\\r\\n\",\"Price\":\"200000\",\"Address\":\"Avenida Eng Francisco Rodolfo Simch\",\"Rooms\":\"1\",\"Suites\":\"1\",\"Baths\":\"2\",\"Year\":\"2010\",\"Area\":\"63.2\",\"AreaTotal\":\"200\",\"Garage\":\"1\",\"PicturePath\":null,\"Extrainfo\":null,\"ID_Realstate_agency\":0,\"ID_Facilities\":0,\"ID_Neighborhood\":2027,\"ViewCount\":null,\"ID_PropertyType\":1,\"ID_Amenities\":0,\"GeoLoc_Lat\":\"-30.1091\",\"GeoLoc_Lng\":\"51.2519\",\"ID_TYPEDEAL\":1,\"rowcount\":0,\"NeighborhoodName\":\"Agronomia\",\"CityName\":\"PORTO ALEGRE\",\"StateName\":\"Rio Grande do Sul\",\"StateUF\":\"RS\",\"PropertyName\":\"Apartamento Padrão\",\"USER\":{\"ID\":3,\"PHONENUMBER\":\"2147483647\",\"EMAIL\":null,\"NAME\":\"Carlos Linares\"},\"IMAGES\":[{\"Id\":0,\"ID_Product\":4,\"PicturePath\":\"2015\/12\/origin_20151227171214875.jpg\",\"Picture_Order\":1},{\"Id\":0,\"ID_Product\":4,\"PicturePath\":\"2015\/12\/origin_20151227171215347.jpg\",\"Picture_Order\":2},{\"Id\":0,\"ID_Product\":4,\"PicturePath\":\"2015\/12\/origin_20151227171215387.jpg\",\"Picture_Order\":3}]}}
```

The problem is that:

1. on a ASMX Webservice > the root node is D, which is odd since Im not adding a root node in .net, I am just serializing the class
2. on Android> When I try to get the value for Node PRODUCTS, by using

   productSearchResult.getJSONArray("PRODUCTS");

I get an JSonException: No value for PRODUCTS. My guess is that the JsonObject is not well formed, this object is a return object by using Webb's HTTP wrapper using the method getBody().

Comment: this json you posted is not valid, why is the array inside of quotes, and you should use `d` not `PRODUCTS`

Comment: if I try to productSearchResult.getJSONObject("d").getString("Id") I still get JsonException

Comment: Actually the error (JsonException) is b/c the d root node is of type string instead of JSonObject. The issue was that this "d" was coming from the JavascriptSerializer in my .net web service. Once adjusted it was coming as a valid JSonObject. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I'm currently using to correct json structure.

```
public static String convertStandardJSONString(String data_json) {
    data_json = data_json.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n", "");
    data_json = data_json.replace("\"{", "{");
    data_json = data_json.replace("}\",", "},");
    data_json = data_json.replace("}\"", "}");
    return data_json;
}
```